# How to set scrollcomposite for one TabItem in SWT?

Tags: java, layout, swt, scrolledcomposite

I am trying the following code to set scrollcomposite for TabItem "item2". But couldn't get the scroll bar.

Here I created two tabItem , where I need to set scrollcomposite / scrollbar for only item2 not for item1

```java
Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);
Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
tabFolder.setLocation(clientArea.x, clientArea.y);
// First Tab Item
TabItem item = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("TabItem " + 1);
Composite comp = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
GridData wgd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
comp.setLayout(gl);
comp.setLayoutData(wgd);
Button button = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Page " + 1);
Button button2 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
button2.setText("Page " + 1);
Button button3 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
button3.setText("Page " + 1);
Button button4 = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
button4.setText("Page " + 1);
item.setControl(comp);

ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

// second tab item
TabItem item2 = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
item2.setText("TabItem " + 1);
Composite comp2 = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout gl2 = new GridLayout();
GridData wgd2 = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
comp2.setLayout(gl2);
comp2.setLayoutData(wgd2);
Button buttonq = new Button(comp2, SWT.PUSH);
buttonq.setText("Page " + 1);
Button button2q = new Button(comp2, SWT.PUSH);
button2q.setText("Page " + 1);

sc.setContent(comp2);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);
sc.setMinSize(comp2.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
sc.setShowFocusedControl(true);
item2.setControl(comp2);

tabFolder.pack();
shell.pack();
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

When I added following code, tabItem2 was empty:

```java
item2.setControl(comp2);
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Several things here.

First use layouts for everything. The `tabFolder.setLocation` is causing confusion, use `FillLayout` instead.

So replace

```java
Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
tabFolder.setLocation(clientArea.x, clientArea.y);
```

with

```java
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```

Second, the `Composite` for the second tab must be owned by the `ScrolledComposite`.

So change

```java
Composite comp2 = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
```

to

```java
Composite comp2 = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
```

Finally the `ScrolledComposite` must be the control for the second tab, so change

```java
item2.setControl(comp2);
```

to

```java
item2.setControl(sc);
```